# How to refresh or update a vrt layer in Qgis?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-2, excel

When using the QGIS SpreadSheet Layers plugin, how do I update the SQLite query without closing and reopening QGIS?  I cannot see a "watch file" equivalent.

The plugin creates and uses a *.vrt file of the same name.  This file lists each of the columns and has a separate SQL query for each column imported from the spreadsheet.

So a more general question is: How to refresh or update a vrt layer in Qgis?